# How to get accurate encoder output for kmeans clustering of similar images

Tags: neural-network, cluster-analysis, conv-neural-network, k-means, autoencoder

I expected that if I trained similar images in an autoencoder the output from the encoder would be similar, hence if passed through a clustering algorithm they would form clusters around the same point. So what I did was to train the model with identical images (basically 60 duplicates of the same image). What I noticed, on the contrary, is that the values from the encoder appear different and when passed through kmeans clustering the points are scattered, which tells me nothing about how related my images are to each other.

[kmeans clustering of 60 duplicate images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvP4E.png)

```
def autoencoderConv2D(input_shape=(228, 228, 1), filters=[32, 64, 128, 10]):
input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
if input_shape[0] % 8 == 0:
    pad3 = 'same'
else:
    pad3 = 'valid'
x = Conv2D(filters[0], 5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv1', input_shape=input_shape)(input_img)

x = Conv2D(filters[1], 5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu', name='conv2')(x)

x = Conv2D(filters[2], 3, strides=2, padding=pad3, activation='relu', name='conv3')(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
encoded = Dense(units=filters[3], name='embedding')(x)
x = Dense(units=filters[2]*int(input_shape[0]/8)*int(input_shape[0]/8), activation='relu')(encoded)
print (x.shape)
x = Reshape((int(input_shape[0]/8), int(input_shape[0]/8), filters[2]))(x)
print (x.shape)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters[1], 3, strides=2, padding=pad3, activation='relu', name='deconv3')(x)

x = Conv2DTranspose(filters[0], 5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu', name='deconv2')(x)
print (x.shape)
decoded = Conv2DTranspose(input_shape[2], 5, strides=2, padding='same', name='deconv1')(x)
return Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=decoded, name='AE'), Model(inputs=input_img, outputs=encoded, name='encoder')


autoencoder, encoder = autoencoderConv2D()
pretrain_epochs = 50
batch_size = 2
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse')
autoencoder.fit(x, x, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=pretrain_epochs)

encoded = encoder.predict(x)

encoded.shape
```

(60, 10)

```
n_clusters = 1
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init=20, n_jobs=4)
y_pred_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(encoded)
```

I also tried this with MNIST dataset with digit-2 being 5958 samples and digit-4 being 50 samples. Using k=2, the clustering gives the result as the figure below which shows no distinction between the two digits. Is there something I'm not doing right as I am looking to apply this technique for image filtering where dissimilar images are distinguished and filtered from the similar ones.

[image: MNIST dataset clustering of 6008 samples - 5958 digit-2 and 50 digit-4]

Comment: These are probably tSNE plots? These do not preserve density and may mislead you to wrong conclusions. From a tSNE plot you can't reliably tell if the results are scattered or not: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263539/clustering-on-the-output-of-t-sne/264647#264647